# DecimalFormat not working properly after windows update

Tags: java, java-7, decimalformat, jdk1.7

Up until recently my code was working fine on my development machine as well as on the deployment server.

Now out of the blue, the **DecimalFormat** does not work as expected and I am pretty sure that is after the **windows 10 Creators Update**.

My code is:

```
double x = 22.44;
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
System.out.println(df.format(x));
```

Output: 22,44 
Instead of 22.44

If i change it to :

```
double x = 22.44;
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0,00");
System.out.println(df.format(x));
```

Output is: 0.22

I am using netbeans 7.4 with jdk 1.7.0_79u (64 bit)
Tried changing my jdk to 1.7.0_80u (32 bit) but made no difference.
Also changed the locale setting for Decimal Symbol and Digit Grouping Symbol but still the same problem.

Anyone with ideas on how to solve this issue?

Comment: I'll check what I get... just a moment

Comment: well, maybe it's a java 7 issue. java 9 (early access) gives no problems... I'll try to check with java 7 soon

Comment: What is the output of `System.out.println(Locale.getDefault(Locale.Category.FORMAT));`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is likely a locale issue - your current code uses the default locale of the system, which may be done differently in Java 7 and Java 8. If you want to use a specific locale you can use:

```
double x = 22.44;
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00", new DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.FRANCE));
System.out.println(df.format(x));

df = new DecimalFormat("0.00", new DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.UK));
System.out.println(df.format(x));
```

which outputs:

> 22,44 (with a comma)
>   22.44 (with a dot)

Answer (score 4):

This will be your system locale, different countries usedifferent characters for the decimal and thousand separator.

You can set the locale in the decimal format to override your system default. Or you can change your system default.